# i need a sip softphone that would on incoming call open an url containing the caller number

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, url, sip, call-manager

The idea is that : a customer call, I automaticly open the page of his accout in my CRM.

On the many SIP softphone on ubuntu (ekiga, linphone,...), the only one that i could make do that is twinkle. It has a very convenient "script_incoming_call" option that does exactly what i need. The problem is that the program is not maintained, so that the gui doesn't work on ubuntu 14.04 (something about qt3).

Linphone seams pretty customable, but i had no luck with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually done in a different way: Your workstation runs a callecenter agent program (it could be a Javascript in the browser), and the PBX tells it that a call has come in, and then this agent program does what is needed: opens a web page in CRM, for example. The call can be terminated on a physical desk phone, or anywhere else, including a softphone.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm in a very small firm and we have no pbx, just a SIP accout from a provider (OVH).

Comment: but what is preventing you from installing a local PBX, like Asterisk or FreeSWITCH?

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider application working with Wine? I've tested tSIP softphone for a short time with Lubuntu. In Settings/Contacts HTTP query URL can be defined in a form of https://www.google.com/search?q=[number] or similar. This URL is not opened automatically (it seems to be obtrusive in my opinion), but when user presses "HTTP QUERY" button (which must be defined first -customizable keypad in a similar way to desk phones with DSS keys).

Comment: Wine ? i'd rather not ....